# My 3D model skin turns black in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, shaders

I downloaded the 3D model of a game, and everything was fine, until I tried to view the model in Cycles, and its skin turned partially black. I think it's because the texture of the skin is transparent, but on EEVEE it looks fine. Could someone help me with this?
[image]

[image]

Comment: You would have to show us your material nodes, otherwise we can only guess

Comment: The textures files are missing. You should pack your file before upload it. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/blend/packed_data.html

Comment: Sorry, I completely forgot about that. I will add it later

Comment: Everything is alright now, sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: why do you plug your texture's alpha to the Subsurface scattering? Is your texture file designed to carry SSS data in its alpha channel?

Comment: I don't know, I extracted the model from a game, and I applied the textures for the clothes, etc,and they work fine, except for the body and the head. It's quite strange, I've never seen a transparent texture for skin, and there is only 2 textures for skin, one for the body and another for the head, i reckecked it on the file from the game.

Comment: ok found why it's missbehaving in cycles, writing answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the shader is set up to use a combination of diffuse and subsurface scattering stored in your diffuse color's alpha channel.

Eevee doesn't treat that material with any kind of transparency unless you specifically ask for it, allowing you o easily store anything in the alpha channel of a file without having to tell Eeevee no not treat it as alpha so it works out of the box. But Cycles automatically reads the texture as having transparency.

To fix this, you need to select you image texture node, and in the sidebar, properties panel, set the alpha to channel packed:

[image: channel packed option]

Do this for every picture file used this way in all your shaders and you should be fine.

You can also change that setting from the Image editor, but it will be located in the sidebar's image tab, image panel:

[image: channel packed again]

Comment: Omg, thank you so much, you can't imagine how many time I waste triying to solve the problem, and it was just that easy. I'm happy that finally is solved, again thank you!

Comment: You welcome, don't forget to mark my post as the answer to your question :)